# How to assign session ID (get from remote host) in Enter-PSSession in powershell like what we do in PSExec (-i)?

Tags: powershell

my question is how to assign an active session ID via Enter-PSSession PowerShell?
I appreciate it if you could check the following description and then help me to figure out a solution:

To run an app with GUI on remote windows PC, I tried two ways:

1. using PSExec.exe, command as: PSExec.exe \\{*REMOTE_HOST*} -u {*USERNAME*} -p {*PASSWORD*} -i {*sessionId*} {*arguments*}
   *sessionId * here got from **remote host** in advance by "query session" command, eg: session id = 9 in the following example:

---

C:>query session
SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
services                                    0  Disc
console                                     1  Conn

> rdp-tcp#64        admin                     9  Active
> rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen

---

One thing I must highlight here is that: I have to assign the active session id in the remote host so that the GUI app can run visibly;
This method does work, however, the con is we need to write PASSWORD in plain strings in scrips/code, which is not secure at all; additionally, there is no other credential in PSExec;
Hence, I turn to the 2nd way:

2. Enter-PSSession in PowerShell
   we could use a certificate credential to log in to the remote host, it is more secure than PSExec.exe;
   However, there is an issue: I can't assign an active session ID like what I do via PSExec, my question is how to give a dynamic session ID via Enter-PSSession PowerShell.

Thanks very much!

I would like to figure out how to assign the active session ID got from a remote host

Comment: A PSSession is not the same as an RDP/console session or a PSEXEC connection.

Comment: yeah, PSSession is different from PSExec.exe, now I am looking for a way how to run an APP with GUI in remote host via PSSession. I don't want the APP run in background, but I expect to see the APP GUI in remote host. I was wondering if there is a way to do that?